setcookie() default secure=true
In php.ini where can I set the default "secure" parameter value to true for the setcookie() call(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#:~:text=match%20all%20subdomains.-,secure,-Indicates%20that%20the
Tried modifying session.cookie_secure but that seems to only apply to session cookie not regular cookies set by setcookie(...);

You can't unless you edit the source code. There is no point to do this since PHP will send secure cookies anyway, instead of you can remove set-cookie headers in your http service.

As stated in the manual page, setcookie() already provides a default for secure and it's false:
 setcookie(
    string $name,
    string $value = "",
    int $expires_or_options = 0,
    string $path = "",
    string $domain = "",
    bool $secure = false, 
    bool $httponly = false
): bool

Having an INI parameter to override this would probably lead to endless head scratching.
Not sure what your exact concern is, but:

You don't need to provide all other parameters if those defaults work for you:
setcookie('foo', 'bar', secure: true);


You can use the newer signature and define your defaults in a central location:
define('DEFAULT_COOKIE_OPTIONS', ['secure' => true]);
setcookie('foo', 'bar', DEFAULT_COOKIE_OPTIONS);


You can write your own wrapper:
function customCookie(string $name, string $value): void
{
    setcookie($name, $value, secure: true);
}     



